# Stream out with Java as BufferedReader Readline() from google cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I've been searching for java examples or java client libraries to stream out csv content from google blob storage and unfortunately no luck yet except app engine or python ones.
We have an application and it uses CharStreams.readLines( ... ) to stream out the data and now that application should be up in compute engine with source data in storage.

Is it possible and if so any documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got perfect examples, actually libraries utilizing guava's bytesource and charsource;

https://github.com/zulily/gcs-buddy/tree/master/src/main/java/gcsbuddy

gcs-buddy
An easy-to-use java client for the Google Cloud Storage (GCS) API.

Features

automatic retry on qualifying API errors
simplified object and prefix iteration
upload/download progress monitoring
ability to read objects directly using Guava's ByteSource and CharSource
convenience functions for identifying "implicit directories", composing objects, and more

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `getObjectData` function in the storage sample here:

https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/storage-cmdline-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/storage/cmdline/StorageSample.java?repo=samples#477

Instead of using the `executeMediaAndDownloadTo` function, use the [executeMediaAsInputStream](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/storage/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/storage/Storage.Objects.Get.html#executeMediaAsInputStream()) function instead. This will return an `InputStream` instance, which you should be able to pass to `CharStreams.readLines`.